# Node.js cluster for only a specific function within an Express app

Tags: node.js, express, node-cluster

I am trying to run a Node.js cluster within my Express app, but only for one specific function.

My app is a standard Express app generated with the express app generator.

My app initially scrapes an eCommerce website to get a list of categories in an array. I want to be able to then scrape each category's products, concurrently, using child processes.

I do not want to have the whole Express app inside the child processes. When the app starts up I want only one process to scrape for the initial categories. Once that is done I only want the function that scrapes the products to be run concurrently in the cluster.

I have tried the following:

delegation-controller.js

```
var {em} = require('./entry-controller');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

class DelegationController {

links = [];

constructor() {
    em.on('PageLinks', links => {
        this.links = links;
        this.startCategoryCrawl();
    });
}

startCategoryCrawl() {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

        for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }
        cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
            console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        });
    } else {
        console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
        process.exit();
    }
}
}

module.exports = DelegationController;
```

But then I got an error:

```
/ecommerce-scraper/bin/www:58
throw error;
^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000
```

Which I am guessing is because it is trying to start the express server again, but it is in use.

Am I able to do what I am trying to do, or am I misunderstanding how Node.js clusters work?

Comment: Express has built in clustering. It has its own isPrimary check internally, so any `app = express()` needs to be done on the main process as well as the workers. Additionally, you're exiting out of all child processes immediately with `process.exit()` so there is no apparent benefit to clustering in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not the case where you make use of cluster module. Instead you need the `child_process` module. This module lets you create a separate process. Here is the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Answer (score 1):

I typically create my own Worker bootstrap that sits on top of my application. For things that need to run once, I have a convenient `runonce` function that is given a name and callback. The function checks the primary process for an open (non-busy process) and sends back the PID. If the PID matches (because all processes will claim ownership) the callback executes. If not, the function returns.

Example:
https://gist.github.com/jonshipman/abe627c687a46e7f5ea4b36bb919666c

NodeJS clustering creates identical copies of your application (through the `cluster.fork()`. It's up to your application to ensure that multiple actions aren't run twice (when they aren't expected to).

I believe, when using Express or https.createServer, it's setup in a way so that it doesn't listen to the same port multiple times. Instead each the prime process will distribute the load internally.